# Convert string containing Hashie::Mash to actual Hashie::Mash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following string, how can I convert it into hashie::mash or how can I take out `user` attributes as json.

```
"#<Hashie::Mash user=#<Hashie::Mash birth_date=Fri, 15 Jan 1988 code=\"test\" email=\"test@test.com\" first_name=\"test\">>"
```

Comment: Why do you have that string in the first place? Is it an option to use the original object directly or to serialize the object into another format (like JSON)?

Comment: @spickermann I have been there. `Hashie::Mash` for no reason does not implement json serializer and if one expects it did, the outcome would be that result of `#inspect`.

Comment: @spickermann there is the db where it is stored as the string, and I want to parse the details of the user from it.

Comment: Can’t a mash be serialized to hash then to JSON, then JSON to hash to mash?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I doubt you’ll get anything better than this:

```
s = "#<Hashie::Mash user=#<Hashie::Mash birth_date=Fri, 15 Jan 1988" +
    " code=\"test\" email=\"test@test.com\" first_name=\"test\">>"

s[/(?<=user=#<Hashie::Mash ).*?(?=>)/].
  split(/(?=[\s\A]\S+=)/).
  map do |s|
    s.
      strip.
      split('=').
      map { |s| s.gsub(/\A"|"\z/, "") }
  end.to_h

#⇒ {"birth_date"=>"Fri, 15 Jan 1988",
#   "code"=>"test",
#   "email"=>"test@test.com",
#   "first_name"=>"test"}
```